# Scriptable IRC client with per-channel encoding and autoperform settings

Tags: linux, script, irc, mirc

I'm looking for an IRC client that would let me set different encoding per-channel, not just per-network. It should be scriptable.

Currently I see those options

- ChatZilla. Has the per-channel options. Scriptable in JS. :)
- Quassel. Encoding setting only per network. Not scriptable.
- XChat. Encoding setting only per network. Scriptable in Perl, Python, maybe others.
- Smuxi. Encoding setting only per network. Not scriptable.
- IRSSI. Encoding per-network at best. Scriptable in Perl.
- KVIrc. Encoding per-channel. Scriptable in Perl and KVIrc language.

The client can be GUI or CLI. I would appreciate if you would additional options to the first & last items in the list that seems working for what I asked (the first one is an in-browser client and eats RAM after a short uptime as the channel messages are an HTML table: adding 500 lines to a table and removing 500 lines has a remarkable memory footprint).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Both irssi and Weechat have per-channel encodings.

- Weechat (scriptable in Perl, Python, Ruby, Tcl, Guile and C [plugins]; actively developed)

  For current buffer:

  ```
  /charset encode koi8-r
  /charset decode koi8-r
  ```

  For a given buffer:

  ```
  /set charset.encode.irc.freenode.#postfix-ru koi8-r
  /set charset.decode.irc.freenode.#postfix-ru koi8-r
  ```

  For a given network:

  ```
  /set charset.encode.irc.rusnet cp1251
  /set charset.decode.irc.rusnet cp1251
  ```

  Global:

  ```
  /set charset.default.encode utf-8
  /set charset.default.decode iso8859-1
  ```

  Note: Weechat always tries UTF-8 first, and uses charset.default.decode as fallback. If this causes problems, it's likely to be fixed quickly when reported.
- irssi (scriptable in Perl and C [plugins]):

  For a given network tag/channel:

  ```
  /recode add freenode/#postfix-ru koi8-r
  ```

  For a given network tag:

  ```
  /recode add rusnet cp1251
  ```

  Defaults:

  ```
  /set recode_out_default_charset utf-8
  /set recode_fallback iso8859-1
  ```

  Note: "network tag" can differ from network name; if you do `/connect freenode` twice, it will open connections tagged `freenode` and `freenode2`.